# How i can get wordpress post using category id?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting problem in wordpress using query_posts.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array('category__in' => array(9),'post_type'=>'banner-slider','post_status'=>'publish');
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_title();
endwhile;
```

query_post return following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  bib_posts.* FROM bib_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND 0 = 1 AND bib_posts.post_type = 'banner-slider' AND ((bib_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY bib_posts.ID ORDER BY bib_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

In the above query, i am getting 0=1 which is wrong. but when i remove category__in from query post then my query working fine.

Please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query_posts is not meant to be used by plugins or themes, more specifically the codex says:

> This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright
>   fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
>   pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
>   making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose.

**Quoted from:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

[image: query_posts]

The WordPress codex recommends using `WP_Query` or `get_posts()`. In your case, I think `get_posts()` should be sufficient, so this example is going to use that. The below example is actually from the WordPress codex, with a couple of modifications for your `category`, `post_type`, and `post_status`:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'category' => 9, 'post_type' => 'banner-slider', 'post_status' => 'publish' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**Codex:** http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts